# Algorithm to minimize number of reads in 2D array

Tags: java, algorithm

Given a 2D array of size x*y with numbers from 1 to x*y or null with the following condition - 
m[x,y] == null ||
m[x,y] > m[x',y'] where (x > x' && y = y') || (y > y')

For example:

```
2X2 array: 
4 0
0 0

2X2 array: 
3 0
0 4
```

Write an algorithm to output the list of numbers that are missing between 1 and x*y with minimum number of reads.

Comment: This looks like homework, if it is, please add the *homework* tag.

Comment: This is not homework, one of questions asked in my interview

Comment: It would help if you posted what you have tried so far. Also, is this question to be implemented in java? I see a java tag, but nothing java-specific in the question.

Comment: I guess the outputs for the examples are [1,2,3] and [1,2]. What are the number of reads? my guess 1 and 4

Comment: @BharatSinha, this is OP's task to add homework tag, not us.

Comment: You really need to clean up that conditional.  I have to guess what you are trying to say. What are the conditions on the x' and y' variables? =(

Answer (score 0):

allocate an array of booleans inited to false of size (x*y)

go over all of the cells in the matrix and set array(M(x,y)) to true

go over the array and print all indexes where array(i)=false

if you are looking for a trick the sum of the missing numbers (sum of 1to(x*y) -sum of matrix) and amount of the missing numbers might be enough to determine what they are

Comment: you didnt specify what the goal number of reads is. "reduced" should be compared to something.

Comment: the goal is to avoid reading all the cells. We need to use the condition to skip reading some cells

Comment: it seems that if you scan the matrix from the bottom right, first up and then to the left. any non zero value would mean that all of the not yet scanned values in the matrix are lower than the current (so it is actually sorted, with missing numbers)

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a solution in C# but can be translated to Java very easy. The main idea is that under the definition of the problem the minimum value in a row is the maximum value that you can expect to find in a previous row. (The same idea is that the maximum value that you found in a row is the minimum value that you can expect in a following row). If you found the maximum value (or minimum) expected for a row you don't have to continue accessing to the matrix because don't have any sense and then you save a lot of steps becoming optimum solution.

```
static List<int> Missing(int[,] matrix, int x, int y)
{
    bool[] numbers = new bool[x * y + 1]; //All values found in the matrix
    int max = x * y; //Max possible value in a row
    int min = max; //Min possible value in a row
    int row = y - 1; //Starting from the last row in the matrix until the first one
    while ((row >= 0) && (min > 1)) //Stop accessing in case that the global possible minimum (value 1) is found in a row greater than first one
    {
        int col = -1;
        do
        {
            col++;
            if (matrix[row, col] > 0) //Assuming that value 0 means null
            {
                numbers[matrix[row, col]] = true; //Mark as found the value in the cell
                min = Math.Min(min, matrix[row, col]); //Update the minimun value of the row (first non zero value in the row)
            }
        }
        while ((col < x - 1) && (matrix[row, col] < max) && (min > 1)); //Inside the matrix range? Stop condition to do not access more elements in that row
        max = min - 1; //Update the possible maximum value for the following row (row - 1)
        row--;
    }
    var result = new List<int>();
    for (var index = 1; index <= x * y; index++)
        if (!numbers[index]) //Return only those values that were NOT found in the matrix
            result.Add(index);
    return result;
}
```

Example of usage:

```
int[,] matrix =
{
    { 0,  2,  0, 11, 0 },
    { 0,  0,  0,  0, 0 },
    { 0, 12,  0, 15, 0 },
    { 0, 16,  0,  0, 0 },
    { 0,  0, 21, 25, 0 }
};
List<int> numbers = Missing(matrix, matrix.GetLength(0), matrix.GetLength(1));
for (int index = 0; index < numbers.Count - 1; index++)
    Console.Write(numbers[index].ToString() + " ");
Console.WriteLine(numbers.Count > 0 ? numbers[numbers.Count - 1].ToString() : string.Empty);
```

Hopefully it'll solve your problem.

Comment: The algorithm is not correct, consider the 4x1 matrix `{ 1, 2, 4, 0 }`

Comment: @Absurd-Mind I'm sorry but the algorithm itself is OK, the wrong part was in the usage code example because I changed the indexes order, instead to call:

List<int> numbers = Missing(matrix, matrix.GetLength(0), matrix.GetLength(1));

we should call:

List<int> numbers = Missing(matrix, matrix.GetLength(1), matrix.GetLength(0));

Now it outputs the correct answer. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: I modified the code to include even more optimizations. In case we found the value 1 in any row, there is no point to continue the loop for lower rows and save lots of access.